# Push to local Azure DevOps Git from Release Pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, pipeline, release

We have some scripts distributed among several Azure DevOps repos.
Our goal is to :

1. Parse all of those repos
2. Extract help info from our scripts and generate .md files
3. Push those .md files to another local Azure DevOps repos

We're using a Release pipeline, with our sources repos as artifacts.

How can we authenticate to this local repos to then push commits?
I got following error:

```
2020-03-31T07:35:31.9598572Z ##[error]*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

Is it possible to use an agent identity or something like that?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to provide username and email before you push:

```
git config user.email "some-email" 
git config user.name "some-username"
```

Comment: Even with this configuration, I got following error when doing the push to remote branch:
`[error]fatal: unable to access 'https://test@dev.azure.com/test/project/_git/repos/': Failed to connect to dev.azure.com port 443: Connection refused`

Comment: the first error you got was to provide the username and email which is later used in commit-logs so you need it anyway. 443? do you use a proxy? Firewall outbound settings?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , at git push step you can try to provide your PAT in push url, like the example below: `git push https://{AzureDevopsPAT}@dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_git/xxx.git`.

To get that token you need to go to security tab to generate personal access token so that we can push code to Azure DevOps repo. We need to choose Read,write & manage in section Code so that we can have permission to push code.

By this way, we can solve the error below:
[image]
[image]